# maxlength not working in ion-textarea in ionic 4 android

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

```
 <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="text"
          id="text-area" type="tel" maxlength="350" >
```

allowing more than 350 characters in android it's working as expected in ios
Expected behavior:
it should stop after input more than 350 chracters

Comment: Can you try with type="text" instead of type="tel"

Comment: both are same still not working

Answer (score 0):

try,

in html:

```
   <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="text"
          id="text-area" type="tel" maxlength="350" > 
     </ion-textarea>
```

in ts file:

```
text = "";
```